# how to get the root parent of a target element- Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a nested elements:

```
<a href="www.google.com">
  <b>Bold test</b>
  <i> Italics </i>
  <span>hello</span>
</a>
```

however the above is dynamically generated content and hence there can be no guarantee that this structure will remain the same. For example: I can also have a structure like:

```
<a href="www.google.com">
  <span>hello</span>
</a>
```

or simply:

```
<a href="www.google.com">click me</a>
```

in all cases I'm trying to get to the  tag using the href attribute:

```
onclick(eve) {
  if (eve.target.href || eve.target.parentNode.href || eve.target.parentNode.parentNode.href) {
    //do something
  }
}
```

basically I do not want to keep checking for parentNode to get to the href attribute of  tag. is there a way to get to  no matter how deeply nested that element is from the target?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can navigate to the nearest ancestor that matches a particular selector string with `.closest`:

```
someElement.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const a = e.target.closest('a');
  if (a) {
    // do something with a.href
  }
});
```

This will work even if the `someElement` is the `<a>` itself.